# Clicar em botão em uma pagina web automaticamente

Tags: javascript

Como simulo um clique em um botão em uma pagina na web automaticamente via JavaScript?

Comment: não teria como tirar a lógica do click do botão para um função e simplesmente chamar ela?

Comment: não entendi o contexto que você está... está usando um webbrowser ? vc esta fazendo a pagina ?

Comment: eu tenho um programa que abre certa página da web sozinha de acordo com o horário do dia. eu quero que ao abrir a pagina automaticamente ele ative o botão da página.

Comment: Que programa seria esse? O que esse clique irá fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para simular um click basta usar o método `click()`, para obter suporte a maioria dos navegadores use a função abaixo.

```js
function click(id)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if(element.click)
        element.click();
    else if(document.createEvent)
    {
        var eventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        eventObj.initEvent('click',true,true);
        element.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
}

click('el');
```

```html
<button id="el" onclick="alert('teste')">
teste
</button>
```

Comment: Duate, A página da internet vai abrir sozinha e tem que apertar um botão sozinha também. no caso ele está pegando o evento do onclick

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui entender o que você quer, essa página é gerada automaticamente? é um iframe? é um load?

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser uma função mais generica, para triggar vários tipos de evento:

```
function trigger (element, eventName) {
  var event,
      eventClass;

  switch (eventName) {
    case 'click': // Dispatching of 'click' appears to not work correctly in Safari. Use 'mousedown' or 'mouseup' instead.
    case 'mousedown':
    case 'mouseup':
      eventClass = 'MouseEvents';
      break;

    case 'focus':
    case 'change':
    case 'blur':
    case 'select':
    case 'submit':
      eventClass = 'HTMLEvents';
      break;

    default:
      throw 'fireEvent: Couldn\'t find an event class for event "' + eventName + '".';
    break;
  }

  event = document.createEvent(eventClass);
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
  event.eventName = eventName;
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Vamos testar.
Coloquei um alert() no evento de click do body

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert('clicou'); });
```

Vamos disparar o evento:

```
trigger(document.body, 'click');
```

Answer (score -1):

Não seria mais prático alguma coisa do tipo:

window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("id_do_botão").click();
};